# How to display data frame contents inside a function

Tags: r, function

I want to see the contents of a dataframe that is created inside a function after the dataframe gets created.

Let's say the dataframe is called df in the function. If I just include a line of code like this:

```
df
```

I don't get any display to the console. I would get the dump of the dataframe contents outside a function.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're expecting it to print out because when you type the name of an object into R's shell, you have the representation of the object helpfully echoed back to you. Inside a function, this doesn't happen unless you explicitly tell R to print the information.

If `print(df)` doesn't work, look for buffered output and be sure it's turned off.

Answer (score 4):

In an interactive session, when you type the name of an object, like `df`, R implicitly `prints()` the object using an appropriate method. It is as if you'd typed `print(df)`, without you actually having to type all those extra characters.

However, there are a few places that this automatic printing is not active

- As you found out, this is not active within functions,
- Within loops, such a `for`, `while` etc.,
- When you source a script.

In such cases, you need to explicitly `print()` an object.

This often catches people out with **lattice** and **ggplot2** plots, which need to be `print()`ed to get them drawn on the device. but in general use, the user never has to explicitly `print()` these plots to get something drawn.

Answer (score 1):

When you type a variable name in the console and hit enter, R silently passes that variable to `print`.  In order to get the same effect from inside a function, you need to explicitly print.  In your case:

```
print(df)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df <- data.frame(x = rpois(100,80))

print_me <- function(x){
  print(x)
}

print_me(df)
```

Comment: Why do you print x instead of df in your example in the print_me function call. It seems you would want to print df to prove the point.

Comment: @Jazzmine i have edited as you mean. x is perhaps too abstract but it means any name should work.